# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting handlers on key binding Ctrl+Shift+R

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to change the functionality of Ctrl+Shift+R in my eclipse RCP application.
By default I am filtering some files when I open window using Ctrl+Shift+R key binding.

The same functionality is working with Navigate -> open resource menu but not with key binding.

I am using the below plugin.xml

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
<actionSet
        label="Resource Navigation"
        description="%NavigateActionSet.description"
        visible="false"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.NavigateActionSet">
     <action
           class="com.project.handler.ResourceHandler"
           definitionId="org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource"
           helpContextId="org.eclipse.ui.open_workspace_file_action_context"
           id="org.eclipse.ui.OpenWorkspaceFile"
           label="Open Reso&amp;urce..."
           menubarPath="navigate/open.ext2">
     </action>
</actionSet>
```

Here, If this **definitionId="org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource"** I am using then Key binding will work according to the Handler class written by me but with the conflict handler exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting handlers: {[ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,com.project.handler.ResourceHandler in com.project),  for 'org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource',  in TrimmedWindowImpl (IDEWindow) Context, activeWhen=AndExpression [children=[ActionSetExpression(org.eclipse.ui.NavigateActionSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@77587422), WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@77587422)]], active=true, sourcePriority=16448, participating=true]} vs {[ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler in org.eclipse.ui.ide),  for 'org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource',  in TrimmedWindowImpl (IDEWindow) Context, activeWhen=AndExpression [children=[ActionSetExpression(org.eclipse.ui.NavigateActionSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@77587422), WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@77587422)]], active=true, sourcePriority=16448, participating=true]} in: PartImpl (de.semvox.odp.workbench.geniosexplorer.GeniosExplorerView) Context
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService$HandlerSelectionFunction.compute(LegacyHandlerService.java:145)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ValueComputation.get(ValueComputation.java:66)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.internalGet(EclipseContext.java:271)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.internalGet(EclipseContext.java:282)
```

And If I change this **definitionId** to something else, then Key binding will work in the default way.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: It might work if you can disable the original action, that may be possible using the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point.

Comment: Do you mean by defining the category in org.eclipse.ui.activities?
And then I need to create Keybinding and command for that?

Comment: You can use the activites extension point to disable existing definitions, this requires research to work out what the definitions are and which plugin defines them.

Comment: the definion id is org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource but when I am trying to do something on this using activities extension point, then open tresource menu is hiding from navigate menu but nothing is happening with key binding(ctrl+shift+R). It is still giving me the same exception.